# AccessViolationException when debug starts

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting a real problem with my app, which I'm not able to solve. About 30% of the times, when I press F5 to debug my application on Visual Studio, I get an AccessVioltaionException at System.Windows.Forms.dll.

What is realy strange is that my application is WPF and I don't have any reference to Windows Forms and I don't use any library that could reference to it. The exception occurs at the beginning of the debug session and my first line of code is not even executed before the exception. It happens with my application just on debug (it never happens if I start my application outside Visual Studio) and it only happens less than half of the times. Sometimes, I have to try to debug 4 or 5 times in a row just for my application to run.

I've searched online and I couldn't find any information or anyone with the same problem. I'm already having this exception since months.

What do you think is causing this exception or what can I do to find the source of the problem?

I'm posting here a printscreen of the exception on Visual Studio. It is in portuguese, but I think you will understand it just from the image.
[image: Exception printscreen]

---

**EDIT:**
I copied the exception details to the clipboard and the result text was the following:

*System.AccessViolationException não foi manipulada
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Tentativa de ler ou escrever na memória protegida. Isto é normalmente uma indicação de que existe outra memória danificada.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       em System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, Int32 wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateWindowIcon(Boolean redrawFrame)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
       em Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunParkingWindowThread()
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:*

After disabling the Visual Studio host process, now the AccessViolationException is thrown on the Show() method of the application window. This is the statck trace of the exception:

```
*System.AccessViolationException não foi manipulada
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Tentativa de ler ou escrever na memória protegida. Isto é normalmente uma indicação de que existe outra memória danificada.
  Source=WindowsBase
  StackTrace:
       em MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CriticalSetWindowTheme(HandleRef hWnd, String subAppName, String subIdList)
       em System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Initialize(HwndSourceParameters parameters)
       em System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
       em System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
       em ASilva.Gamer.Dialogs.ProgressWindow.Show(String title, String text) em C:\Users\ASilva\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gamer\Gamer\Dialogs\ProgressWindow.xaml.cs:line 124
       em ASilva.Gamer.App.StartupApplication(IEnumerable`1 args) em C:\Users\ASilva\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gamer\Gamer\App.xaml.cs:line 634
       em ASilva.Gamer.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) em C:\Users\ASilva\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gamer\Gamer\App.xaml.cs:line 1263
       em System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
       em ASilva.Gamer.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) em C:\Users\ASilva\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gamer\Gamer\App.xaml.cs:line 499
       em System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
       em System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       em System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       em System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       em MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       em System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       em MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       em MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       em System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       em System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       em MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       em MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       em System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       em System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       em ASilva.Gamer.App.Main()
  InnerException:*
```

Comment: If you get an exception, then you should at least try to get its full stack trace. And does this exception happen in your application or is it a Visual Studio error? Perhaps you use some VS extensions that can crash, don't you?

Comment: The exception don't show any code or details, I don't know how to get more information about it. But, I really never thought about extensions. I only use two. I will try to disabled them and see what happens. It is an exception on the application, not a Visual Studio error, I think.

Comment: Perhaps you can at least PrintScreen it and post as an image?

Comment: Have you tried to enable "Just my code" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx) in options, this seems vaguely familiar. It could just be a handled exception that is unrelated to your program.

Comment: I have "Just my code" option enabled. It was enabled by default,

Comment: Do you know if Visual Studio needs to load Windows.Forms.dll for some reason when debuging a WPF application?

Answer (score 3):

> I don't have any reference to Windows Forms

Well, not you.  But when you debug your app then you really do use Winforms, the stack trace doesn't lie.  It is not your code, it is code that the debugger uses that created that dependency.  Easy to get rid of, use Project > Properties > Debug tab > untick the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option.

Do keep in mind that this is not a Winforms bug.  It is just the canary that died in the coal mine.  The hosting process uses the SystemEvents class.  In order to get the notifications and fire its events, the class needs to create a window.  It is hidden, it just serves to get the notifications delivered.

And the code that died is code that should never die, setting the icon of a window (normally visible in the upper left corner) should **never** throw an exception like that.  The name of the program gives a hint of sorts, owned by somebody that cares about the way their windows look.  It is the kind of crash that's induced by utilities that alter the appearance of the window chrome.

You need to get your machine fixed.  It is pretty broken.

Limp along by disabling the hosting process.

Comment: You're right, this application use WindowChrome. Bu disabling the visual studio host process, as you suggested the AccessViolationException is thrown on the method that show the first window. I will update my question with the new stack strace.

Comment: Well, lucky hit on the name.  Repeating, your machine is broken.  You have right now 20 good reasons to uninstall "WindowChrome", whatever the heck it is.

Comment: "It is just the canary that died in the coal mine." made my day :-)